# web server works on container but not on Windows 10 host

Tags: docker

I'm running my container with:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 dockerimage:tag
```

I then enter the container and fire up the web server but it binds on ipv6..
I can get it to run by uncommenting 2nd line of /etc/hosts.

But even then there's a problem: I cannot visit the page with my browser from the host.

127.0.0.1:8000 works from within the container (using curl)

127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't work from the host.

I also tried with the container's ip address.

```
netstat -an on the host gives me ::1 8000 and ::1 9000 .
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: get the ip address of host using ipconfig and try using it along with port

Comment: Doesn't work, could not connect to server.

Comment: Go into control panel -> network and internet -> Network Connections, find the adapter "vEthernet (DockerNAT)", go into properties, and uncheck the box for IPv6, then restart docker.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto my comment for clarity, you'll want to disable IPv6 for the docker virtual adapter, you can find this in the control panel, under network and sharing center -> Network Adapters (or Network Connections, depending on your control panel view)

Make sure IPv4 is checked, then click Ok, and restart docker, viola, your containers should now be defaulting to IPv4.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I still can't access the server from the host. Now netstat reports: [::1]:8000    [::]:0   LISTENING . Do I have to rebuild the container?

Comment: Is this a common problem?